# POST form data with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

Hi i'm trying to do some validations to my contact form and after that sending the data with AJAX, the validations worked well and the was sent OK by the native way in HTML, but when i tried to do it throw AJAX the index is still refreshing and the Indicators of the AJAX does not work...this is my code, what is the problem?

the jquery:

```
$('form').submit(function (e)
{
    var illegalchars=/[^a-zA-Zא-ת\ ]/;
    var phonechars=/[^0-9\-]/;
    var mailfilter=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    var errorDiv = $(".form_error");

    var fullName = $("input[name='full_name']").val();
    var phone = $("input[name='phone']").val();
    var email = $("input[name='email']").val();
    var text = $("textarea[name='text']").val();
    var time = $("textarea[name='time']").val();
    var robCheck = $("textarea[name='rob_check']").val();

    if ( fullName == '' || phone == '' || email == '' || text == '') {
        errorDiv.html('אחד השדות ריק, וודא כי כל השדות מלאים');
        errorDiv.fadeIn('slow');
        setTimeout("$('.form_error').fadeOut(1000);", 3000);
        return false;
    };

    if ( fullName.length < 4 || phone.length < 4 || email.length < 4 || text.length < 4) {
        errorDiv.html("באחד מהשדות הזנת מס' תווים נמוך מהרצוי");
        errorDiv.fadeIn('slow');
        setTimeout("$('.form_error').fadeOut(1000);", 3000);
        return false;
    };

    if ( phonechars.test(phone) ){
        errorDiv.html("הזנת תויים לא חוקיים בשדה של הטלפון");
        errorDiv.fadeIn('slow');
        setTimeout("$('.form_error').fadeOut(1000);", 3000);
        return false;
    }

    if ( !mailfilter.test(email) ){
        errorDiv.html("הזנת תויים לא חוקיים בשדה של האימייל");
        errorDiv.fadeIn('slow');
        setTimeout("$('.form_error').fadeOut(1000);", 3000);
        return false;
    }

    if ( illegalchars.test(fullName) ){
        errorDiv.html("הזנת תויים לא חוקיים בשדה של השם המלא");
        errorDiv.fadeIn('slow');
        setTimeout("$('.form_error').fadeOut(1000);", 3000);
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
            url: "send_contact.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: ("#contact_form").serialize(),
            timeout:5000,
            dataType: "php",
            async:true, // TRUE=Continue scripting, FALSE=Stop Everything
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#loader').css({
                    "display":"block"
                })
                return false;
            },
            error: function(){
                errorDiv.html('משהו השתבש');
                errorDiv.fadeIn('slow');
                setTimeout("$('.form_error').fadeOut(1000);", 3000);
                return false;
            },
            success: function(msg){

                if(msg == 'problem'){
                    errorDiv.html('משהו השתבש');
                    errorDiv.fadeIn('slow');
                }
                else{
                    errorDiv.css({"background":"rgba(60,196,0,1)"})
                    errorDiv.html('עודכן בהצלחה');
                    errorDiv.fadeIn('slow');
                }

                setTimeout("$('.form_error').fadeOut(1000);", 3000);
                return false;
            },
            complete: function(){
                setTimeout("$('.form_error').fadeOut(1000);", 3000);
                return false;
            }
        });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

the HTML:

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
                <div class="right">
                    <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="שם מלא:" /><br />
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="טלפון:" /><br />
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="אימייל:" /><br />
                    <input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo ($date); ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="rob_check" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="left">
                    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="שלח!" />
                </div>
                <div class="breaker"></div>
                <div class="form_error"></div>
            </form>
```

the PHP:

```
<?php

if ( $_POST['rob_check'] != ""){
    echo 'you have a problem with your form!!';
    return false;
    die();
}

else if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

$name = trim( $_POST["full_name"] );
$email = trim( $_POST["email"] );
$phone = trim( $_POST["phone"] );
$text = trim( $_POST["text"] );
$time = $_POST["time"];

//print_r($_POST);die();

$to = 'adirkandel@gmail.com';
$subject = "פורטפוליו";
//$headers = '';
$message = "
    <html>
        <head lang='he'>
        <title>$subject</title>
        </head>
        <body dir='rtl'>
            <h2>נושא ההודעה: $subject</h2>
            <p>$text</p>
        <hr />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>שם השולח</th>
                    <th>טלפון השולח</th>
                    <th>אימייל השולח</th>
                    <th>נכתב בתאריך</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$name</td>
                    <td>$phone</td>
                    <td>$email</td>
                    <td>$time</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    ";

$message = str_replace("\'", '&#39;', str_replace('\"', '&#34;', $message)); //remove slash before qoutes

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
//$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>';
//$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

**OK guys i found all the problems:

1. i needed to add "$" before "data: ("#contact_form").serialize()" so thanks you Subha!.


2. i need to add "&submit=submit" to the "data: $("#contact_form").serialize()" like this: data: $("#contact_form").serialize() + "&submit=submit", because i needed to post value to the "submit".


3. i accidently wrote in the "dataType: 'php'" instead of 'html'.
thank you every one for your help!**

Comment: Please give more information than 'it does not work'. What have you tried to solve the problem? Is your server-side code being hit? Is there are errors in the console? And so on...

Comment: the console shows me a problem with "Status Code:302 Found" and value of the submit action does not post to the page, and if you we will look on the php code i did it as a condition to send the mail: else if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ), what do you reccomend to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a $ sign in the following line..

data: ("#contact_form").serialize(),

This should be -

data: $("#contact_form").serialize(),

Comment: thanks it was 1 problem but now the console shows me a problem with Status Code:302 Found and value of the submit action does not post to the page, and if you we will look on the php code i did it as a condition to send the mail:
    else if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ), what do you reccomend to do now?